# How can I get the first thread related to only the specified users?

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to write a query to get a thread that is related to only the specified users.

I've included some dummy data and my table schema below, as well as the expected output with some edge cases.

Any help is appreciated.

#### users

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | User 1 |
|  2 | User 2 |
|  3 | User 3 |
+----+--------+
```

#### threads

```
+------+----------+
| id   | title    |
+------+----------+
|    1 | Thread 1 |
|    2 | Thread 2 |
|    3 | Thread 3 |
+------+----------+
```

#### thread_user

```
+-----------+---------+
| thread_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       1 |
|         2 |       1 |
|         2 |       2 |
|         3 |       1 |
|         3 |       2 |
|         3 |       3 |
+-----------+---------+
```

**Pseudo Query**

```
select all from threads where related user id's are exactly 1 and 2
```

**Expected Output**

```
+------+----------+
| id   | title    |
+------+----------+
|    2 | Thread 2 |
+------+----------+
```

`Thread 2` **is** in the list of results because it's related to only `User 1` and `User 2`.

`Thread 1` **is not** in the list of results because it is only related to `User 1` and **not** `User 2`.

`Thread 3` **is not** in the list of results because it is related to `User 1` and `User 2` **and** `User 3`.

Comment: include some sample data and expected output. It can't be comprehended in its current from. Have you tried a JOIN? If so show your query.

Comment: Sample data means sample contexts for each of these tables. Sample output means what you want as a result of the query.

Comment: @danblack Is my most recent edit more informative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit to handle case 3 as well

```
select t.id, t.title
from users u
inner join thread_user tu on tu.user_id = u.id
inner join threads t on t.id = tu.thread_id
inner join (select thread_id
from thread_user
group by thread_id
having count(*) = 2) sq on sq.thread_id = t.id
where u.id in (1,2)
group by t.id, t.title
having count(*) = 2
```

I am not at my dev environment, so can't check for syntax correctness, but something like this should work,

```
select t.id, t.title
from users u
inner join thread_user tu on tu.user_id = u.id
inner join threads t on t.id = tu.thread_id
where u.id in (1,2)
group by t.id, t.title
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - seems to be along the right lines, but `Thread 3` is still returned in the results. Looks like it's because the where in stops `User 3` from ever being fetched, so it assumes both `Thread 2` and `Thread 3` have a count of 2.

Comment: I see the issue, please take a look at the updated answer. It might not be most efficient but should work.